# Extending type of function argument

Tags: typescript

I have function as follows:

```js
async paginate(
    msg: Message,
    title: string,
    data: Array<any>,
    message: (
      currentData: any,
    ) => Promise<string | { title: string; description: string }>,
    perPage = 10,
  ): Promise<void> {
      // Function code here
  }
```

I can't determine the type of `data`, and it can be an array of any type.

I want to make `currentData` have the same type as `data` provided in the second argument.
For example, if `data` i provided is an array of string, `currentData` should have a type of string, not any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) here:

```
async paginate<T>(
    msg: Message,
    title: string,
    data: Array<T>,
    message: (
      currentData: T,
    ) => Promise<string | { title: string; description: string }>,
    perPage = 10,
  ): Promise<void> {
      // Function code here
  }
```

Essentially this tells Typescript that `data` is an array of type `T`, and and the `message` takes a parameter named `currentData` which also has type `T`, where type `T` will be decided later during the function call. So, if your data type is `string`, you call it like this:

```
paginate<string>(
 // parameters
)
```

and when data is something complicated, say, of type `Person` defined as `type Person = {name: string, age: number}`, you could call the same function with the new type argument like this:

```
paginate<Person>(
...
)
```

And your `data` and `currentData` will be validated against `Person` type.

Here is a short example

```ts
type Message = number;
function paginate<T>(
    msg: Message,
    title: string,
    data: Array<T>,
    message: (
      currentData: T,
    ) => Promise<string | { title: string; description: string }>,
    perPage = 10,
  ): Promise<void> {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

// OK
paginate(1, '123', [1,2,3], (a: number) => Promise.resolve('something'));
// OK
paginate(1, '123', ['a','2','3'], (a: string) => Promise.resolve('something'));

// Error
paginate(1, '123', ['a','2','3'], (a: number) => Promise.resolve('something'));
// Error
paginate(1, '123', [1,2,3], (a: string) => Promise.resolve('something'));
```

[TSPlayground link](https://tsplay.dev/jwg41N)